# How do we know whether an interpretation of a formula is true or false?

Tags: computer-science, first-order-logic, model-theory

1. Is it correct that an interpretation for a first order logic system
   is defined for the first order language of the logic system, without
   the axioms and inference rules in the logic system being considered?
2. When we study whether an interpretation is a model for a given
   formula in a first order language, how do we know whether the
   interpretation of the formula is true or false?

   Does an interpretation    include a function which assigns truth
   values to all the propositions (i.e. the meanings of all the
   formulas provided by the interpretation)? How is such a function constructed, if the interpretation
   doesn't contain counterparts of axioms and of inference rules?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how a model for a first order signature is defined? An interpretation assigns an element of the model for each variable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the interpretation which is true or false: We say that *a formula* is true or false *under* an interpretation.

> 1. Is it correct that an interpretation for a first order logic system is defined for the first order language of the logic system, without the axioms and inference rules in the logic system being considered?

Yes. An interpretation for a language of FOL is one which is defined for all the non-logical symbols (individual constants, function symbols, predicate symbols) of the language, independently of the axioms that hold in a language.

> 2. When we study whether an interpretation is a model for a given formula in a first order language, how do we know whether the interpretation of the formula is true or false?

I'm not sure I correctly understand your question. The truth value of a formula is already defined relative to interpretations, so checking the truth value of a formula under an interpretation just means recursively applying the definitions of the semantics.

> Does an interpretation include a function which assigns truth values to all the propositions (i.e. the meanings of all the formulas provided by the interpretation)?

No. Unlike in propositional logic, where interpretations directly assign truth values to propositional letters, in FOL interpretations only assign meanings to the non-logical symbols (that is, the individual constants, function symbols and predicate symbols), and the truth value of propositions is then recursively computed relative to this interpretation.

> How is such a function constructed, if the interpretation doesn't contain counterparts of axioms and of inference rules?

In principle, as long as it follows the definition of a first-order structure, you can define your interpretation however you want, if you're talking about just in general interpretations of FOL. If you are in a specific theory, you will have a certain language, and want an interpretation relative to that language, and if you want an interpretation that is a model of the theory, i.e. in which all the theorems of the theory are true, you will have to think more closely about what your interpretations must look like so they satisfy all the axioms.
But normally in mathematical practice, it goes the other way round: You have a mathematical structure with an intended interpretation for the symbols in mind, and you try to find a logical system that describes exactly this structure. Semantics first, axioms and inference rules second. This "intended interpretation" will then be the **standard model** of the theory, though in general there also exist non-standard models which satisfy the axioms of the theory as well. For example, the structure of the natural numbers with the intended definitions of addition, multiplication etc. is the standard model of Peano arithmetic, which is a first-order theory whose axioms describe exactly how addition etc. behaves, and thus the formulas that are true in all interpretations that are models of the theory (such as the standard model) are precisely the facts about natural number arithmetic.

---

As said, I'm not entirely sure I understood your question correctly because I would assume that if you talk about interpretations and theories of FOL, you already know how the semantics of FOL works, i.e. what an $\mathcal{L}$-structure with domain and interpretation function is, and how the truth value of a formula relative to an interpretation is defined recursively. In that case, I think you will have to rephrase your question to make it clearer what you want to know about.
But if you don't know what an FOL interpretation is, which your second question seems to suggest, I strongly recommend you first grab a good book that teaches the basics of FOL, before going into things such as axioms and first-order theories. It doesn't make much sense here for me to repeat the definitions of the semantics of FOL, which you will find explained in much more detail along with examples. After understanding what an interpretation is, your questions might resolve themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that the assignment of propositions to truth values is done in terms of basic set theory for the domain set of the interpretation. Proposition "x1=x2"  is true iff they are the same element in the domain set. Proposition "R(x1,...,xn)" is true iff (x1,...,xn) is in relation R over the domain set. Proposition "not P" is true iff P is false. Proposition "P1 and P2" is true iff both P1 and P2 are true. ...

Comment: Yes, correct. So whether a formula is true under an interpretation depends on which relations the interpretation defines, rather than the interpretation directly assigning a truth value to the proposition. Does this anser your question?

Comment: An interpretation doesn't include the function which assigns truth values to propositions.

Comment: Not in the case of first-order logic, correct.

Comment: yes in which logic?

Comment: In propositional logic aka statement logic, where an interpretation is a valuation function which assigns to each propositional letter a truth value.

Comment: I would separate the interpretations of relation, constant and function symbols, as being part of the *model*.

Comment: @lemontree propositional logic is first order logic without quantifiers, so an interpretation in a propositonal language is a restriction of an interpretation of a first order language. How do you get an interpretation for a first order language,  from "an interpretation"  for a propositional language which "is a valuation function which assigns to each propositional letter a truth value".

Comment: @Berci What do you mean by "separate the interpretations of relation, constant and function symbols, as being part of the model"?

Comment: @Berci I agree, terminology can be confusing here. I like to use "interpretation" as a generic term to refer to valuation functions in PL, structures in FOL and more complicated semantic "structures" in other logics. For the part of the model that assings a meaning to the nonlogical symbols I use "interpretation *function*". And I tend to reserve the term "model" for a structure that satisfies a given formula/theory.

Comment: @Tim No, it is not. The language of PL is different from that of FOL and so is the way they are interpreted. You don't get an interpretation of FOL from one of PL, it's a different thing.

Comment: Again, this will make much more sense after you read up in detail on how the semantics of PL and FOL is defined.